# Como creo un boton con una imagen en python tkinter

Tags: python, imagen, tkinter, botón

amigos mi pregunta es como creo un boton y al boton insertarle una imagen, soy nuevo con python tkinter, si me pueden ayudar muchas gracias.

Intente con esto:

```
img = PhotoImage(file='actualizar.png')
botonNuevo1 = tkinter.Button(text="test", width=500, height=500, image=img,justify="right")
botonNuevo1.place(x=500, y=100)
```

y me queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar pack() para organizar. Según tu ejemplo, el código sería el siguiente.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root = tkinter.Tk()  
root.geometry("960x600")
img = Image.open('actualizar.png')
img = img.resize((1000, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS) # Redimension (Alto, Ancho)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
botonNuevo1 = tkinter.Button(root, image=img, text="asdfasdf", compound="top")
botonNuevo1.place(x=500, y=100)
botonNuevo1.pack() 

root.mainloop()
```

Pack() te ayuda a controlar la posición del objeto. También se puede usar grid().

Te dejo un tutorial donde se explica a detalle: [Posicionar elementos en Tcl/Tk (tkinter)](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/posicionar-elementos-en-tkinter/)

Use la librería `PIL` para redimensionar la imagen.

Comment: Si, ahora queda pero el texto y la imagen no se ven, es decir o se ve la imagen sola o el texto solo  y yo quiero que se vean las dos tienen alguna idea de como solucionarlo?, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: y una ultima cosa sabes como dimensionar la imagen?, es decir cambiar el largo y alto de la imagen

Comment: @Franco Acabo de editar el código par que acepte texto. Además use la librería PIL para redimensionar la imagen. Saludos)

Comment: Ahora si, el ultimo problema que tengo es que no puedo alejar la imagen del texto es decir yo quiero a la imagen mas a la izquierda y el texto mas a la derecha no que esten pegados y con compound no puedo darle medidas solo dirección, muchas gracias por toda la ayuda

Comment: @Franco revisa el enlace que publiqué, ahí explica a detalle todo eso.

Comment: Ya lo revise y no lo logre solucionar

Comment: @Franco vale, publica el código que intentaste hacer, o dime que parte no entiendes

Comment: img = PIL.Image.open('images.png')
img = img.resize((25, 10), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS) # Redimension (Alto, Ancho)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
botonNuevo1 = Button(image=img, text="Actualizar", compound="left",command=funcion,bg="#d2d2db",fg="black",font=("verdana",10),width=200,height=35,bd=0)
botonNuevo1.place(x=0, y=208)  y me queda asi: https://imgur.com/NzTpg3s y yo lo que quiero es alejar la imagen mas a la izquierda me explico?

Comment: @Franco revise tu código, la única solución que se me ocurre es poner el texto con espacios por adelante (no se si afectará el tipo de fuente tamaño etc), me quedó así https://imgur.com/4nTZVgW 
text="_AGREGAR_ESPACIOS__Actualizar"

Comment: Si, funciona pero el texto queda muy a la derecha y me gustaría que este en el medio, pero bueno si no se puede hacer nada lo dejare así hasta encontrar otra solución, muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda!